# How do I find the coordinates of the two closest points to my point in a list

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates

I have a list of values and a given point and I want to find the coordinates of the two closest points (one inferior and one superior).

For example:

```
list = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
point = 0.7
```

I want my return value to be [1, 2] since 0.7 is between 0.5 and 1.

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the return value be [0.5, 1] ? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kinille I want the coordinates but I also can get them if I have the values

Comment: Oh, you mean you want the indexes of the closest coordinates.

Comment: @Kinille Exactly that (sorry if I wasn't very clear)

Comment: Suppose list is [ 1,1, 1, 1, ..., 1 ] and point is 1, what should be returned?

Comment: @MarkLavin probably an error message. In my application that would never happen because the list is a result of a np.linspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compute distances and then exploit `numpy.argsort`:

```
import numpy as np

def closest_n_indexes(distances, n=2):
    return np.argsort(distances)[:n]

point_list = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
point = 0.7

distances = [abs(p-point) for p in point_list]

closest_n_indexes(distances)
Out[8]: array([1, 2])
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the given list is always sorted as it is in your example and that it has for sure one value below and one value above your given point, then you can loop over the list until you find a value larger than the given point and then return a list containing that index and the index below it.

```
def two_closest(_list, point):
    for index, value in enumerate(_list):
        if value > point:
            return (index-1, index)
    raise Exception("Malformed parameters")
```

For larger lists, you could speed this up with binary search or other heuristics. For example, you said your list is created by np.linespace, you could find the exact place your coordinate would lie between if you knew how the list was created.

Answer (score 1):

If `list` is in sorted order you can use python's built-in binary search library.  It's very fast:

```
import bisect

def get_bracket(lst, target):
    lindex = bisect.bisect_right(lst, target) - 1
    rindex = lindex + 1
    return [lindex, rindex]

print(get_bracket([0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3], 0.7))
```

which prints:

```
[1, 2]
```